# Partial fraction of $\sec(z)$ from $\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-fractions

Given
$$\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi z)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{z-n},$$
is there a fast way to get
$$\sec(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)\pi}{z^2-(n-1/2)^2\pi^2}?$$
I've tried computing it, but I get a huge mess. Would anybody have some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's rewrite your first equation as :
$$\frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi/2-\pi z)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{z-n}$$
and set $\ x:=\pi\bigl(\frac 12-z\bigr)\ $ then (dividing by $\pi$) :
$$\sec(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  \frac {(-1)^n}{\pi z-\pi/2-(n-1/2)\pi}$$
for $m:=-n$ :
$$\sec(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac {(-1)^n}{x+(n-1/2)\pi}-\sum_{m=0}^\infty  \frac {(-1)^m}{x+(-m-1/2)\pi}$$
for $n':=m+1$ :
$$\sec(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac {(-1)^n}{x+(n-1/2)\pi}+\sum_{n'=1}^\infty  \frac {(-1)^{n'}}{x-(n'-1/2)\pi}$$
Putting everything together we conclude :
$$\sec(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)\pi}{x^2-(n-1/2)^2\pi^2}.$$

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, this is much better than my reckless bashing.

Comment: @mathstudent12: Thanks for that! The idea here was to put the positive half-integers at the left and the negative ones at the right.