# How to prove this identify for Catalan zeta function?

Tags: trigonometry

The Catalan Zeta Function is defined as
$$
\beta(n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^n}.
$$
For example, we have $\beta(1) = \pi/4$, $\beta(3)=\pi^3/32$, $\beta(5)=5 \pi^5/1536$.

I am trying to prove this identity
$$
\beta(2n+1) = (-1)^n \left(\frac \pi 2 \right)^{2n+1}\frac{E_{2n}}{2 (2n)!},
$$
where $E_n$ denotes [Euler numbers](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.2#ii).

As I know that
$$\sec z=1+\frac{z^{2}}{2}+\frac{5}{24}z^{4}+\frac{61}{720}z^{6}+\cdots+\frac{(-%
1)^{n}E_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n}+\cdots.$$
I only need to show that
$$
\sec\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{\beta(2n+1)}{\pi/4} x^{2n}.
$$
But I got stuck here.

The question comes from [The Computer as Crucible](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Books/Crucible/crucible.pdf) (see pp. 60). A clue is to use *"an appropriate product for
$cos(\pi x / 2)$".*

Comment: Why not just use good ol' induction?

Comment: $\beta(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (2k+1)^{-s}$ is the [Dirichlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function). There is no known closed-form for $s= 2n$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes... and that relates... how?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0101168.pdf ... is worth a gander.

Comment: You can prove the last equation starting from the partial fraction decomposition of $\sec$, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210698/partial-fraction-of-secz-from-frac-pi-sin-pi-z

Comment: Catalan zeta, Dirichlet beta... gosh, I'd call it the $L$-function of the nontrivial character mod $4$. In any case, computing its explicit values at odd exponents should run pretty closely to calculations of the Riemann zeta-function at even integers. Sit down with a proof of the Riemann zeta evaluation and try to modify the steps to fit this Dirichlet series instead.

Comment: It's calculating $L(s,\chi)$ for odd positive integer $s$ where $\chi$ is the Dirichlet character of conductor $4$. One can do this by evaluating $L(s,\chi)$ at negative integers and using the functional equation.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Mittag-Leffler expansion, 
$$ \sec{\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)} = 1+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{z-(2n+1)}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right) = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{2n+1}{z^2-(2n+1)^2}. $$
You can then expand the fraction about $z=0$ to get
$$ \frac{2n+1}{z^2-(2n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{2n+1} \frac{1}{1-\left( z/(2n+1) \right)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2k}}{(2n+1)^{2k+1}} $$
and interchanging the order of summation will give the result.

Answer (score 1):

Show that $$f(z)  =\frac{\pi^2\sin(\pi z)}{\cos^2(\pi z)}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(z+k+1/2)^2} $$
($\frac{\pi^2\sin(\pi z)}{\cos^2(\pi z)}-\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(z+k+1/2)^2}$ is a bounded entire function vanishing at $i\infty$)

and look at $f^{(2n-1)}(0) = (2n+1)! 2^{2n+2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)^{2n+1}}$.

Also $f(z)$ is the derivative of $\frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi z)}$ (related to the Euler numbers)